# Is Newton's third law held in special relativity regarding Coulomb's force?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electrostatics, atomic-physics

Assume a charged mass $(m,+q)$ is revolved around another charged mass $(M,+q)$ at a distance $r$ so that $M>>m$, yet the gravitational effects are negligible. (Such as an electron orbiting a proton.) If the orbital speed of $(m,+q)$ is small compared to that of light, the Coulomb's force of $F_{Mm}$ exerting from the E-field of $(M,+q)$ onto $(m,+q)$ equals the force of $F_{mM}$ exerting from the E-field of $(m,+q)$ onto $(M,+q)$, and thus Newton's third law is held.

However, if the orbital speed of $(m,+q)$ is a considerable fraction of that of light, using the relativistic form of coulomb's law, we have:

$$F_{Mm}=E_{Mm}q=\frac{q^2}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r^2} \space ,$$

$$F_{mM}=E_{mM}q=\frac{\gamma q^2}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r^2}  \space ,$$

where $\gamma=1/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$, and $v$ is the orbital speed of $(m,+q)$. As we see $F_{Mm}\not=F_{mM}$, and Newton's third law is violated. However, does this mean that, because of a non-zero net force, the system of our particles would momentarily tend to linearly accelerate so that, say $(M,+q)$, hobbles around a point?

Please discard the radiation of $(m,+q)$ by assuming the centrifugal acceleration as negligible. Remember that it is physically possible to make the centrifugal acceleration close to zero $(a=r\omega^2\approx 0)$, while the tangential velocity remains close to light speed. $(v=r\omega\approx c)$

**Besides**, the relativistic Coulomb's law indicates that the net electric field outside a neutral atom, like Hydrogen, is not exactly zero, due to the fast orbital speed of the electron that produces a greater E-field than that produced by Hydrogen's proton at a specific point outside the atom. **Does this non-zero electric field cause anomalous behavior of the neutral atom as subjected to an external E-field? Has this anomalous behavior been seen experimentally so far?**

Comment: "due to the fast orbital speed of the electron that produces a greater E-field than that produced by Hydrogen's proton at a specific point outside the ato " There is no orbital speed in quantum mechanics, just probabilities and  interactions, which in the relativistic regime are computed  with QED .Feynman diagram sums, and they are inherently Lorenz covariant. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital

Comment: *Please discard the radiation* This is not possible. The violation of the third law means that momentum is being exchanged with radiation.

Comment: @anna v  Then forget about QM. Consider the problem macroscopic. Both $(m,+q)$ and $(M,+q)$ have considerable masses and charge, that is.

Comment: Then there can be no orbits, the particles would radiate and fall on each other ( the reason quantum mechanics was invented. If you are thinking of classical charges and masses in space,  there might be an effect but how to measure it?

Comment: @Ben Crowell Radiation depends on acceleration, and as I said, we can minimize it to zero. Afterward, we can consider Newton's third law for short periods of time when any radiation is negligible.

Comment: The electromagnetic field around a moving particle is not just the spherically symmetric Coulomb electric field. The electric field is contracted and there is a magnetic field too. I wonder if this is the source of your discrepancy

Comment: @octonion The magnetic field produced by $(m,+q)$ cannot affect  $(M,+q)$ because $(M,+q)$ is not moving through the mentioned magnetic field. And yes, the contraction of the E-field shows itself as the Lorentz factor that I obtained in $F_{mM}$.

Comment: Two $+q$ charges can’t be a proton and electron, and they wouldn’t revolve around each other.

Comment: @MohammadJavanshiry, Yes, fair enough, but that magnetic field is still important because the electromagnetic field has momentum density proportional to $E\times B$ (the Poynting vector). Even if you constrain the particles to be moving linearly, this integrated field momentum would change, and its derivative should be equal to the discrepancy in the third law.

Comment: @octonion Can you prove it?

Comment: @MohammadJavanshiry, I'm pretty sure I can, but it takes a bit of a calculation. Maybe I'll write an answer later, but by all means beat me to the punch by doing the calculation yourself if you're interested